# SAP Hybris 6.7 Media Management

Tags: e-commerce, crm, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement of restricting media format to jpeg and png for media upload.
Hybris version is 6.7.0.
Is there and OOTB feature that can be used to achieve the same?

Comment: Capitalization and additional tags

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a validation to achieve this. Let's say you have this requirement for the application storefront then you can validate/restrict the supported types using the JS & Server-side(validator) checks. I believe you can do the same for the backend cockpit as well.

Comment: Is there any OOTB feature to achieve the same?

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I don't remember any